# Deploy Ruby on Rails to Elastic Bean-Stalk route errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, routes, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I just deployed an Ruby on Rails application on the Elastic Bean-Stalk (AWS). When I try to visit the URL of the app, I get the following lines in the log file. What could be the cause of this issue ? Is it from the Gemlist ? What gems do I need for production ?!

```
-------------------------------------
/var/app/support/logs/production.log
-------------------------------------
...
I, [2016-01-05T21:12:14.107404 #22655]  INFO -- : Started HEAD "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-05 21:12:14 +0000
F, [2016-01-05T21:12:14.179737 #22655] FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [HEAD] "/"):
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  passenger (4.0.59) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:74:in `process_request'
  passenger (4.0.59) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:141:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  passenger (4.0.59) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:109:in `main_loop'
  passenger (4.0.59) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:455:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
```

Comment: in routes.rb check root 'controller#index'

Comment: assuming you have routes.rb configured, what's your rails version?

Comment: make sure your route supports HEAD requests to /

Answer (score 1):

ElasticBeanstalk now checks the health of your app by making a HEAD request to the root path. The response status of this HEAD request must be 200 for your app to be considered in OK (Green) health. [Here's a link with more info](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/events.common.httphead.html).

To solve this, in routes.rb, wire root to a controller method that will return any response.

For example:

```
class HealthController < ApplicationController #health_controller.rb
  def index
    render json: {status: 'success'}
  end
end


# routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'health#index'
  ...
end
```